# xercesc NodeType not declared

Tags: xerces-c

I am developing an application to read XML files using xerces-c-3.1.1 using C++ on Netbeans 8.0.1.

I have a variable defined as type DOMNode* as follows

```
   DOMNode* attribute=attributes->item(aIndex);
```

When I expand attribute in the debugger, it displays a function, getNodeType(), that returns a variable of type.  However,when I add the code

```
 NodeType value=attribute->getNodeType();
```

I get the error message

```
error: ‘NodeType’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: You could try `::xercesc::DOMNode::NodeType` instead of writing `NodeType`

Comment: xercesc::DOMNode::NodeType works!!  Thanks very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `xercesc::DOMNode::NodeType` instead of writing `NodeType`.